# Distributing External Assemblies with Application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dependencies

The below image is the external assemblies that my Solution references, generated using `Architecture` **→** `Generate Dependency Graph` in Visual Studio 2012

[image: Dependency Graph]

Currently my Project is targeted for .Net 4.5. If I distribute all these external assemblies (dlls) as part of my assembly.

1. Will it run on a PC having .Net Framework 4.0.

I also have a feeling like, When I execute my exe (.Net 4.5) on a PC with .Net 4.0, internally OS will look in Registry, whether I have .Net 4.5 installed for this application to run, before actually location the references dll in the same folder.

Comment: 1 - try (does not sound like a good idea), 2 - SO is not place for legal advice, read license yourself/ask lawyer - feel free to remove second part of the question.

Comment: I'm completely lost on connection between "free to download" and "violating ... license"... With your comment I don't think this question is good fit for SO - collection votes/opinions is not goal for SO...

Comment: Well fine, removed Question 2.

Comment: You can create Installation with FW4.5 silent. It will not install if determines that it is already installed. You need all the third party components licensed for re-distribution. And you need all of your Dlls.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not run on a PC with only the 4.0 framework.  See the [MSDN Version Compatibility article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Apps).

Regarding redistribution, [you're allowed to redistribute the .NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xak0tsbd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  [EULA Agreement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994405.aspx)

Check with other component vendors for their policies.  According to [this forum post](http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Distribution-td5437218.html), you need the NLog dll and license text file to be included.  StackOverflow isn't really good for legal advice, so I'd check your third-party components directly.

Comment: Side note: your second half (on licensing) does not answer OP's question ("can I copy individual DLL instead of following proper installation of pre-req").

Comment: True, but I would say that one should really either require the framework be installed as an installation prerequisite, or to bundle the framework with the installer; this wouldn't just work if you provide the DLLs, permitted or no.